# On recieving email on Google-Apps send a request to a server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Is it possible upon receiving an email on, lets say `support@example.com` which is maintained on a google business apps account, to make a server/api-request to a server with the body and senders email?

So this workflow:

- Email sent to: support@example.com
- Email received on google business apps platform
- Server call to: https://api.example.com/v2/post/
- With post parameters From, Body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

Quick overview:

1. Create script using [UrlFetch Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) and [Gmail Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/): check inbox, if email found, post to API, mark email as processed (I would use labels to mark as processed).
2. Run script from #1 using [Time-Driven Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_time_triggers).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by [routing the email on to Google AppEngine](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2368151&topic=1227584&ctx=topic) and making use of [AppEngine's mail receive APIs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail).